# Run Cucumber JVM tests manually

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have a bit of a special situation. Basically I have a unit test, annotated with @Test, and inside that test I need to execute a Cucumber JVM test class.

Why? Long story. Something to do with classloaders and RoboGuice, it's not very important but it does impose limits on what I can and cannot do.

Here's the test method:

```
@Test
public void runCucumberFeature() throws Exception {
    Cucumber cucumber = new Cucumber(MyCucumberTest.class);
    cucumber.run(new RunNotifier());
}
```

MyCucumberTest is a class I have created, and annotated like this:

```
//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}, strict=true)
public class MyCucumberTest {
    // Empty, as required by Cucumber JVM
}
```

Why have I commented out the @RunWith annotation? Because if I don't, the Cucumber test runner will pick up the test and run it, which I don't want because I am running the test manually.

The problem is that the above doesn't work. It looks like Cucumber is finding the feature files, it is verifying that MyCucumberTest contains the @Givens etc, it even prints out the test as if it was running it.

But it doesn't. No code is executing inside the @Given, @When and @Then methods. I'm not sure why this is, but I have a vague idea that the Cucumber JVM test runner doesn't want to execute the code because the class isn't annotated with @RunWith.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't provide the solution you're looking for, but....

... have you considered tagging the test that you want to run manually (e.g. with `@Manual`)?

Then you could uncomment your `@RunWith` annototation and exclude the manual test by adding `--tags ~@Manual` to your Cucumber-JVM invocation.

In your manual JUnit invocation you could add `--tags @Manual`

Comment: I did not know there was a @Manual tag. It might help. Thanks for the suggestion, it's the best so far :-)

Comment: The tags are user defined - use tags that make sense to you. You can apply multiple tags to a scenario, which makes it possible to build up test suites for specific purposes (e.g. \@Regression, \@Defect_54321 etc.)